# Why monitor bytes sent and received on mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to know why we should monitor bytes sent and received on mysql ?
I hope I have not asked a vague question.

Thanks.

Comment: I rarely see MySQL questions on `Bytes_sent` and `Bytes_received`. +1 for introducing these status variables in a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's identify each status variable:

- [Bytes_received](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_received): The number of bytes received from all clients.
- [Byte_sent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_sent): The number of bytes sent to all clients.

The only place I can think of where these number would make sense would be in the network. These status values represent the amount of data passing in and out of DB Connections. These bytes would most likely be visible from another perspective: the Operating System.

You could measure the amount on incoming/outgoing traffic in [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) against MySQL's view of it. If the amount of incoming data is low, or if the amount of outgoing data from MySQL is significantly higher than [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) says, check MySQL and/or the network. You may also want to look for any signs of dropped packets along any interfaces.

In light of this, when it comes to tuning, the only thing I can think of that you may want to tune is setting two things:

- [net_buffer_length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length) : Connection and result buffer size
- [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) : Maximum packet size used internally by MySQL

What is a MySQL Packet ?

According to the [page 99 of the Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596009577)

[image: Understanding MySQL Internals]

here are paragraphs 1-3 explaining it:

> MySQL network communication code was
>   written under the assumption that
>   queries are always reasonably short,
>   and therefore can be sent to and
>   processed by the server in one chunk,
>   which is called a *packet* in MySQL
>   terminology. The server allocates the
>   memory for a temporary buffer to store
>   the packet, and it requests enough to
>   fit it entirely. This architecture
>   requires a precaution to avoid having
>   the server run out of memory---a cap
>   on the size of the packet, which this
>   option accomplishes.
>
> The code of interest in relation to
>   this option is found in
>   **sql/net_serv.cc**. Take a look at **my_net_read()**, then follow the call to **my_real_read()** and pay
>   particular attention to
>   **net_realloc()**.
>
> This variable also limits the length
>   of a result of many string functons.
>   See **sql/field.cc** and
>   **sql/intem_strfunc.cc** for details.

Given this information, you may want to

- raise [net_buffer_length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length) to its max value of 1048576
- raise [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to 256M, 512M, or 1G (especially if you have BLOB data)

Answer (score 1):

**Bytes received:** The values indicates the amount of incoming network traffic to the MySQL server
**Bytes sent:** The values indicates the amount of outgoing network traffic from the MySQL server

You can determine the network bandwidth between MySQL server and Clients.
You can record this variable value periodically for debugging purpose in the events like if you observe high activity on server, high network I/O etc...